# how to connect to remote Mysql server from docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, authentication, database-connection

I am trying to connect to remote Mysql server from a docker container.

I have username and password for the user.

I know the user is created with

```
user'@'localhost
user'@'IPaddress_of_a_machine_from_which_i_can_login
```

Now I am running docker on a machine (the same as IPaddress_of_a_machine_from_which_i_can_login)
And my container is running an application (Apache Nifi) which will use mysql connector to connect to DB.

I am getting connection error to mysql server, which is obvious.
Error:

```
Access denied for user 'dwh_admin'@'<ip of container>' (using password: YES))
```

I am here to ask what should be done to get the connection working ?

Please help me if i need to change the way how the user is created in remote Mysql ?

I think there would be better way, but could not frame properly to get a answer from goolge..

**update**

I am trying to achieve this with Docker compose.
and i have 2 services.
For First service I need to give a static IP address, so that 2nd service can communicate with it --> I achieved this with static IP.
Now I need 2nd service to get IP address of host machine.

below is my sample docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
# version control for nifi flows
    registry:
        hostname: DWH_Nifi_registry
        container_name: nifi_registry_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi-registry:1.22.0' 
        restart: on-failure
        user: root
        ports:
            - '18080:18080'
        environment:
            - LOG_LEVEL=INFO
        volumes:

        networks:
                nifi_persistent_network:
                        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.1

    nifi:
        hostname: DWH_Nifi_prod
        container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi:1.19.0'  
        restart: on-failure
        user: root
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
        environment:
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
                  
        volumes:
            
        networks:
            - nifi_persistent_network
networks:
  nifi_persistent_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.1.0.2
```

Update:

---

After trying compose suggested by Alex, below is the error:

Note: My server on which docker is running is not using port 8080 for any other service, as i checked.

```
nifi_container_persistent           | 2023-07-08 11:22:34,960 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
nifi_container_persistent           | java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to DWH_Nifi_prod:8080
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:814)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:172)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:83)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332)
nifi_container_persistent           | Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
nifi_container_persistent           |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Unknown Source)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Unknown Source)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Unknown Source)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
nifi_container_persistent           |   ... 10 common frames omitted
nifi_container_persistent           | Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
nifi_container_persistent           |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)
nifi_container_persistent           |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
nifi_container_persistent           |   ... 12 common frames omitted
nifi_container_persistent           | 2023-07-08 11:22:34,963 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown started
nifi_container_persistent exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your container using Docker's host network to share the network stack with the host machine, and so it would appear to MySQL as if the connection was coming from the host machine. However, this could have other side effects, such as conflicts if your Docker application uses the same port as another service on the host machine.

You can use Docker's host network by adding --network host when you run your Docker container, like this:

```bash
docker run --network host -d your_image
```

You can specify the network mode for a service inside your docker compose using the `network_mode` parameter.  The network_mode: host line makes the Docker container share the network stack with the host machine

Using your docker-compose ...

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    # version control for nifi flows
    registry:
        hostname: DWH_Nifi_registry
        container_name: nifi_registry_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi-registry:1.22.0' 
        restart: on-failure
        user: root
        ports:
            - '18080:18080'
        environment:
            - LOG_LEVEL=INFO
        networks:
            nifi_persistent_network:
                ipv4_address: 10.1.0.1

    nifi:
        hostname: DWH_Nifi_prod
        container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi:1.19.0'  
        restart: on-failure
        user: root
        environment:
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
        network_mode: host

networks:
  nifi_persistent_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.1.0.2
```

Note that a service running in host network mode is not part of any Docker network, and it communicates using the Docker host's network stack.  If `other_service` needs to communicate with `mysql`, it would need to use the Docker host's IP address, not `localhost` or the static IP address. Similarly, if `mysql` needs to communicate with `other_service`, it would need to use the static IP address.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Can i make this inside docker compose ? Following your lead, I tried assiging static IP to my container : ```"        networks:
                persistent_network:
                        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.1" ``` where 10.1.0.1 is my host machine IP. I am getting "java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)" error. So might be a different approach for this in docker compose ?

Comment: @santhosh see my updated answer with instructions for docker compose

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I had updated my docker compose in question. If i use network_mode: , then i could not give static IP for other service correct ?

Comment: See my updated answer.  You should be able to assign a static IP to a different service in your compose file, though it can complicate communication between the two services.

Comment: I actually tried with this docker-compose, but its failing. Error pasted in question as its too long for comment.

Comment: I think this is likely because the NiFi server is running in host network mode, and so the hostname directive is not applicable because the container doesn't have its own isolated network environment.

Can you try removing the `hostname: DWH_Nifi_prod` line from your Docker Compose file.

Comment: perfect!! this is the culprit..  Thanks to you /\ . Marking this as answer.